# Lodash/FP pick in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, lodash

I have this lodash/fp function(pick)

```
<MyComponent initialValues={pick(
        [
         value1,
         value2
        ], props.user
    )}
```

It supplies me value1 and two from `props.user`
How can i pick some other values from another props(they have to be on the smae component[i'm using reactJS] and the same field)? 
I tried with the `&&` operator and making another pick like

```
<MyComponent initialValues={pick(
        [
         value1,
         value2
        ], props.user
      ) && 
      pick([value3], props.user.userMeta)}
```

Also i tried outsourcing this logic into a function, where i simply call the two picks but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.flow()` with `_.over()` to generate a function that takes props, extract the properties (`_.get()` and `_.pick()`), and then merges them together:

```js
const { flow, over, get, pick, mergeAll } = _

const createGetInitValues = (userValues, userMetaValues) => flow(
  over([
    flow(get('user'), pick(userValues)),
    flow(get('user.userMeta'), pick(userMetaValues)),
  ]),
  mergeAll
)

const props = { user: { a: 1, b: 2, userMeta:{ c: 3 }}}

const getInitValues = createGetInitValues(['a', 'b'], ['c'])

const result = getInitValues(props)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spread both the picked values :

```
<MyComponent
        initialValues={{
          ...pick([value1, value2], props.user),
          ...pick([value3], props.user.userMeta),
        }}
/>
```